# I cannot reach the name property in the API

Tags: javascript, reactjs, frontend

I am working on a weather app project. The problem is I cannot reach the name property in the API call.

Here is the API response:

```
{cod: '200', message: 0, cnt: 40, list: Array(40), city: {…}}
city: {id: 745042, name: 'Istanbul', coord: {…}, country: 'TR', population: 11581707, …}
cnt: 40
cod: "200"
list: (40) [{…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}, {…}]
message: 0
[[Prototype]]: Object
```

Here is my ApiCall component:

```
import axios from "axios"
import { useEffect, useState } from "react"

function ApiCall({ getCities }) {
    const[data, setData] = useState({})

    useEffect(() => {
        axios(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Istanbul&appid=c681e6e33ec339728fdf88e0b24a2a01`)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data))
        .catch(err=> console.log(err))
    })

    const { city, list } = data
    console.log(city.name)
```

Finally, this is the error I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')
```

Answer (score 1):

Since API calls are asynchronous, you need to wait for the response before you assign the value to the state. Thus, you need to move the code inside the `then` block. Then it will work:

```js
function ApiCall({
  getCities
}) {
  const [data, setData] = useState({})

  useEffect(() => {
    axios(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Istanbul&appid=c681e6e33ec339728fdf88e0b24a2a01`)
      .then(res => {
        const data = res.data;
        const {
          city,
          list
        } = data
        console.log(city.name)
      })
      .catch(err => console.log(err))
  }, [])
```

Also add an empty array `[]` to your `useEffect` hook if you want to load the API on page load.

Comment: It still gives me the same error. Also, I don't understand what  "const data" comes from

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you look into how React `useState` and `useEffect` work.

### Firstly:

The effect didn't run yet

```
const [data, setData] = useState({}) // This declares the state

// This effect is not run until the component has already rendered.
useEffect(() => {
    axios(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Istanbul&appid=c681e6e33ec339728fdf88e0b24a2a01`)
    .then(res => console.log(res.data))
    .catch(err=> console.log(err))
}, [])
// Pass in an empty array, otherwise there is an infinite loop. 
// Comment if you don't understand why

// Since the effect didn't run yet, the first time around data will be undefined (or rather {} which is the default you set in the `useState`).
const { city, list } = data
console.log(city.name)

// This means, you can't access `data.city.name`, since `data` doesn't even have a `city` property (which is to say `data.city` is undefined, explaining the error message)
```

This means the first time your function is called (the first render), the data has not loaded yet.

### Secondly

Even after you load it, you haven't updated the state:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
    axios(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Istanbul&appid=c681e6e33ec339728fdf88e0b24a2a01`)
        .then(res => console.log(res.data)) // You're not calling setState
        .catch(err=> console.log(err))

// Since you didn't call setState, all the function does is log it to the console after the render
})

// Even the second time around, since state was not updated, it remains `{}`
const { city, list } = data
console.log(city.name)
```

### The Solution:

```
const [data, setData] = useState({})

useEffect(() => {
    axios(`https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast?q=Istanbul&appid=c681e6e33ec339728fdf88e0b24a2a01`)
        .then(res => setState(res.data)) // setState
        .catch(err=> console.log(err))
})

const { city, list } = data
console.log(city?.name) // Should log `undefined` first, then the real result
```

*EDIT*: The solution logs `undefined` first because the first time the component runs, it hasn't fetched the data yet. The order goes:

- Initial Render (data has not yet loaded)
- `useEffect` called after the render. This loads the data
- `useEffect` changes the state via `setData`
- Since state has changed, the component rerenders (runs again). This time the data is there since it has loaded

Comment: It worked. Thanks for helping, but there is one thing I did not understand. Why did you use the question mark in here "console.log(city?.name)" and why does it return "undefined" at first?

Comment: Let me address that in an edit @Hyperienn

Comment: Thanks for replying. The last thing I want to ask why did you use question mark and what is the purpose of it in that log? Also, should I use aysnc function when I call the API